# automatic navigate using routing in Nativescript

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

can you ask me any idea, how to navigate automatic, or reload in FirstPageComponent ? Or any idea. I want only to open FirstPageComponent

I have this routes.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'image', component: ImageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

In HomeComponent I have this code:

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an empty path object to the Routes like this:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to open `FirstPageComponent`, not `HomeComponent`

Comment: In this case you need to update the route to '/home/fp' and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Which will trigger your auth guard I believe, so make sure the correct auth is provided.